# Web app for running ant task

Tags: web-applications, command-line, ant

Does anyone know of a simple web app that supports running ant tasks?  Alternatively it could run command line programs.  I need to allow the user to choose parameters for running the ant task.  I effectively want a web interface to run the ant task and provide any parameters.

I can write one but this is generic enough that it seems like there should already be a few standard packages that do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give [Anthill](http://www.anthillpro.com/html/products/anthillos/download.html) a shot.  They have an open source version.  This will periodically check your source code repository, and run a specified ant task any time the code base changes.  You can also manually trigger builds.

Answer (score 0):

You could put this in a PHP-file:

```
echo shell_exec('ant');
```

It would run ant and return the output to the browser.